# Definitions in windows standard libraries not accessible

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm playing with web service sample. I have error variable that is passed to various functions.

```
WS_ERROR* error = NULL;
```

I would like to know how this error is constructed. I press `F12` on `WS_ERROR` and now I'm on `WebServices.h` have definition:

```
typedef struct _WS_ERROR WS_ERROR;
```

Well, `WS_ERROR` is structure `_WS_ERROR`. Going deeper to `_WS_ERROR` by pressing `F12` on `_WS_ERROR` and stop! I can't go deeper to `_WS_ERROR` definition. Why? So, how `_WS_ERROR` is defined?

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to see inside. MSDN says "An opaque type used to reference to an error object." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: It is an *opaque* type, you are not supposed to know what it looks like.  It carries "rich errors", a way to find out more about what exactly went wrong when a function fails.  You must create the error object with WsCreateError().  And query it after a failed call with WsGetErrorString().  After which you probably use WsResetError() to clear it again so it is usable for the next call.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an [opaque type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), i.e. something the programmers didn't want you to put your nose into (for whatever reason).

A pseudocode example: imagine a company has a library they want you to use through a public API but don't want you to know how they're handling things under-the-hood, they would just hand you a library file and a header file to link against it, e.g.

- Header.h

  ```
  // Public header to link against something
  #pragma once

  typedef struct FakeStruct* FakeStructPtr; // Opaque type

  DLL_PUBLIC void public_api_function(FakeStructPtr obj);
  ```

you would use the `FakeStructPtr` as explained in the API reference and pass your `FakeStruct` objects (created by other API functions) to some `public_api_function`.

Internally the company might do something like

```
// Internals
#include "Header.h"

struct RealDataType {
    int realdata1;
    float realdata2;
    // whatever..
};

void public_api_function(FakeStructPtr obj) {
    RealDataType* ptr = reinterpret_cast<RealDataType*>(obj); // Cast to real data
    // use the real data through RealDataType..
}
```

and ensure you would not end up taking a look at their internal datatypes (except if you used some reversing or someone got a wrong debug build public).